# How to append content to querySelectorAll element with innerHTML/innerText?

Tags: javascript, append, innerhtml, innertext

I currently have my class element:

```
var frame_2 = document.querySelectorAll(".name");
```

Currently this div is empty. I now want to "append/add" some content to that div - I had a go with `innerHTML` + `innerText` but for some reason nothing seems to be added.

**Example:**

```
frame_2.innerHTML = '<img src="image.gif" />';
```

and

```
frame_2.innerText = 'some text';
```

Any suggestions? Im not sure if there are ways of doing the same - or performance'wise something better?

Comment: document.querySelectorAll(".name")[0] -> you get a list and want the first item

Answer (score 21, accepted):

this gives you a list of elements that contain the class name

```
var name=document.querySelectorAll(".name");
```

you want the first element?

```
name[0].textContent='some text';
```

This gives you one single element, the first one.

```
var name=document.querySelector(".name");
name.textContent='some text';
```

To *append* stuff

```
name.appendChild(document.createTextNode('pizza'));
name.appendChild(document.createElement('div')).textContent='spaghetti';
name.appendChild(document.createElement('img')).src='cookie.jpg';
```

**EDIT**

To get the elements by classname, then retrieve the id :

```
var names=document.querySelectorAll(".name"),l;
while(l--){
console.log(names[l].id);
}
```

or if i didn't understand correctly

html

```
<div class="spaghetti" id="pizza"></div>
```

js

```
document.querySelector(".spaghetti#pizza")
```

**EDIT2**

html

```
<div id="container1"><div class="my-class"></div></div>
```

js

```
document.querySelector("#container1>.my-class")
```

Comment: Hi cocco, thanks a lot for your answer.
For the single element selector: document.querySelector(".name"); - is it possible to refer to it more precise - like imagine I have class .name inside two different containers, one with id called: "name-container-1" the other "name-container-2"

Comment: you want to get an element by id?

Comment: nope. I want to get it by classname, but I want to target the class name within a specific id container

Comment: i added a script on how you can get the individual id of every element.

Comment: Ahh sry for not being precise - the scenario is: <div id="container1"><div class="my-class"></div></div>

Comment: But dont delete your latest example, that could come in handy :) Thanks so much for the effort - youve done more than needed.

Comment: The first edit (EDIT) for getting element by class and id saved me. Nice work!

Answer (score 4):

Easier solution, any use case. Query your selector:

```
let find = document.querySelector('.selector');
```

create some html as a string

```
let html = `put your html here`;
```

create element from string

```
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = html;
```

Append new html you created to selector

```
find.appendChild(div);
```